# Javascript - Automatic video playlist

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to know how could I achieve a video playlist without any buttons or control that would simply play an array of videos and would start again when the last is over.

I found this piece of code about a clickable playlist : http://jsfiddle.net/e8CbF/ 
but I really don't know how to make it automatic. Also, the array is coming from a PHP variable, how I can I use it inside this code ?

```
function loadVids(vidsArray){
 for(var a=0,b,f=document.createDocumentFragment();b=vidsArray[a];++a){
  var c=document.createElement('div');
  c.textContent=b;
  f.appendChild(c);
 }
 d.appendChild(f);
}
var video=document.createElement('video'),vids=['http://screen.alifts.com/screenfiles/video1.mp4','http://screen.alifts.com/screenfiles/video2.mp4'], /* Is it there that I should put the php array ? */
d=document.createElement('div');
d.onclick=function(e){if(e.target.parentNode==this){
 video.src=e.target.textContent;
 video.play();
}} 
document.body.appendChild(video);
document.body.appendChild(d);
loadVids(vids);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a total mess. So i completely rewrite it.

```
<video src="" id="player"/>

<script>
var video=counter=0;

videos=['<?php echo join("';'",$array);?>'];

window.onload=()=>{
    //get the video frame
    video=document.getElementById("player");
    //if the video ended, play next.
   video.addEventListener("ended",play,false);
    //start
    play();
}

var play=()=>{
    //add the video src
    video.src=videos[counter];
    //play next video next time
    counter++;
    if(counter==videos.length){
         counter=0;
    }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's indeed more friendly like this. Can I add an echo in the "videos=[]" as I would do in an html tag ? So I can give it the value of my array ?

Comment: Right now my videos sources are in an array. So I guess I should do a loop to add them in a string, something like : 
`loop() 
{ 
$listvideo = " \" " . $myarray[i] . " \" " . ","; 
} ` ?

Comment: Oh indeed ! Thank you for your kind help !

Comment: Could you ( if everything works fine ) mark my answer as answer? To tell all the others, that they dont need to open this question